# How to get select options from django models?

Tags: python, django

I am not able to render product in my order model on my html page. I am trying to find out the problem here. but as i select form.product.model_name it should get me the model names, but its blank in options. Below I am attaching the code to check it out,

in my models.py

```
from cgi import print_form
from email.policy import default
from enum import unique
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ProductModel(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True, default = '0')
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=" ")
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=" ")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_id)

productchoice = (ProductModel.objects)
        
class OrderModel(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    Customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Father_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Village = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Tehsil = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    District = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ForeignKey(ProductModel, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default= 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order_id)
```

in my view.py

```
from email import message_from_binary_file
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderModel, ProductModel
from .forms import OrderForm, ProductForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

# Create your views here.


def home(request):
    order_form = OrderForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        order_form = OrderForm(request.POST)

        if order_form.is_valid():
            order_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your data was successfully added!'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, order_form.errors)

        
    orders = OrderModel.objects.all()
    
    context = {'order':orders, 'form':order_form}
    return render(request,'Orders/addorder.html',context)

def product(request):
    product_form = ProductForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_form = ProductForm(request.POST)

        if product_form.is_valid():
            product_form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Your Products is successfully saved!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request,product_form.errors)

    products = ProductModel.objects.all()
    context = {'product':products, 'form':product_form}
    return render(request,'Orders/addproduct.html',context)
```

my html page

```
{% extends 'OMS/index.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    <title>Order</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'addorder.css' %}">
    <div class="container mp-3">
        <h1>Create your Order</h1>
        
         <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <label for="Customer Name" class="form-label">Customer Name: </label>
                {{ form.Customer_name }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Father Name" class="form-label">Father Name: </label>
                {{ form.Father_name }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Village" class="form-label">Village: </label>
                {{ form.Village }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="Tehsil" class="form-label">Tehsil: </label>
                {{ form.Tehsil }}
            </div>       
            <div> 
                <label for="District" class="form-label">District: </label>
                {{ form.District }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="State" class="form-label">State: </label>
                {{ form.State }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <select name="product" id="productselection">
                        {% for form in form %}
                            <option value="{{ form.product.product_id }}">{{ form.product.model_name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div> 

           
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            {% if messages %}
                <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

my form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import OrderModel, ProductModel, productchoice
 

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    Customer_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class":"input"
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = OrderModel
        fields = "__all__"
        

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: It should be `order_form=OrderForm()` and `product_form=ProductForm()` and also try to maintain separate condition for GET request in else condition. And what's the error, what's the exact problem?

Comment: Acutally, for selection of product from product model in orderform there is no option displaying at the html page. it is a blank dropdown menu

Comment: I'll check it, later.